# IOS AddressBook Contacts Null Issue on real device

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios8, abaddressbook

I am getting contacts from addressBook and i tested it on simulator there is no first or second name null issue.

But when I trying to test it on real device it give me first or second name Null issue on many rows. please help me my source code is

```
- (void)getContactsWithAddressBook:(ABAddressBookRef )addressBook {
    contactList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
    CFIndex nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook);

    for (int i=0;i < nPeople;i++) {
        NSMutableDictionary *dOfPerson=[NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

        ABRecordRef ref = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allPeople,i);

        //For username and surname
        ABMultiValueRef phones =(__bridge ABMultiValueRef)((__bridge NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonPhoneProperty));

        CFStringRef firstName, lastName;
        firstName = ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
        lastName  = ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonLastNameProperty);
        [dOfPerson setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", firstName, lastName] forKey:@"name"];

        //For Email ids
        ABMutableMultiValueRef eMail  = ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonEmailProperty);
        if(ABMultiValueGetCount(eMail) > 0) {
            [dOfPerson setObject:(__bridge NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(eMail, 0) forKey:@"email"];

        }

        //For Phone number
        NSString* mobileLabel;

        for(CFIndex i = 0; i < ABMultiValueGetCount(phones); i++) {
            mobileLabel = (__bridge NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(phones, i);
            if([mobileLabel isEqualToString:(NSString *)kABPersonPhoneMobileLabel])
            {
                [dOfPerson setObject:(__bridge NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, i) forKey:@"Phone"];
            }
            else if ([mobileLabel isEqualToString:(NSString*)kABPersonPhoneIPhoneLabel])
            {
                [dOfPerson setObject:(__bridge NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, i) forKey:@"Phone"];
                break ;
            }

        }
        [contactList addObject:dOfPerson];
    }

    NSLog(@"Contacts = %@",contactList);
}
```

Comment: have you made sure the second name has a value for all these contacts?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you don't have first name/last name for those contacts so you can do this

```
NSString *firstName = (__bridge NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty)==nil?@"":(__bridge NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);

NSString *lastName = (__bridge NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty)==nil?@"":(__bridge NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty);
```